# Is it always more semantically correct to use <img> rather than <div> or <span> to do CSS sprite?

Tags: html, semantic-web, css-sprites, semantic-markup

I used to do CSS sprite with a `<div>`, but is it actually better to do it with an `<img>` and apply CSS to it with either `display: block` or `display: inline-block` so that it is more semantically correct? (because it actually is an image).

Comment: CSS sprites are good for background images, as those are only “ornaments”, not content. Using them for actual content images does not make much sense IMHO – not when semantics is what you are after. Using an actual image element would allow you to provide an `alt` text at least; but – if you where to embed the sprite image directly as `src` of the img element, it would only make sense in combination with the `clip` property; and the only other option would be to use a “blank” image and apply the sprite as background image …

Comment: … and both would either lose all meaning (background-image) or deliver too much information (full image when given as `src` and `clip` not working on it) if CSS was not available.

Comment: @CBroe for example, I can only think of as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22621944/what-html-element-should-be-used-for-a-label-title-under-images number (3), that if it is a game, and the character's images are displayed using CSS sprite (such as a memorization game)

Comment: Well, for a game things might lay a little different … first question would be, are semantics that important in such a context anyway? Without JS and CSS it might not work anyway, and whether or not a memory-style game is something that f.e. blind users (that could actually benefit from having a real `img` element instead of something semantically “meaningless” with just a background image there) would want to play is doubtful I think …

Answer (score 3):

No.

- If the image is part of your **content**, specify it in the HTML.
  `img`, `object`, ….
- If the image is part of your **design**, specify it in the CSS.
  `content`, `background-image`, …

It *is* possible to [specify design (decorative) images in the HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/embedded-content-0.html#a-purely-decorative-image-that-doesn%27t-add-any-information) (using an empty `alt` attribute), but this is not recommended:

> Purely decorative images are visual enhancements, decorations or embellishments that provide no function or information beyond aesthetics to users who can view the images.
>
> […]
>
> While it is not unacceptable to include decorative images inline, it is recommended if they are purely decorative to include the image using CSS.

However, I’d say that specifying sprites (containing different images) in the HTML is rarely elegant. **What would be the alternative content?** Example: a sprite containing a portrait of a person and the site logo. It might work for most users to specify the alternative content of the image *part* that is currently shown (controlled by CSS), but this would obviously fail for users with image but without CSS support. Those would see the *whole* image file, which wouldn’t make sense in that context.